# Having trouble diagnosing a heap buffer overflow

Tags: c

I'm trying to analyze a function that a project partner wrote to try and figure out why it's giving me a heap buffer overflow.  I have run this through valgrind and cppcheck, but they didn't bring me any closer.

The function is designed to parse through a string and pull out a value to sort on.  Special cases to handle were null values, and movie titles with commas in them.  (Since we're parsing a CSV file, if data has a comma in it, that data needs to be handled differently.)  Here is the relevant snippet:

```
char* findKey(char lineBuffer[], int columnNumber ){
    char tempArray[512];
    int commasCounted = 0;
    int i =0;

    for(i = 0; i< 1024; i++){
        if (commasCounted == columnNumber){
            commasCounted = i;
            break;
        }

        if (lineBuffer[i] == '\"'){
            while(lineBuffer[i] != '\"'){
                i++;
            }
        }

        if (lineBuffer[i] == ','){
            commasCounted++;
        }
    }

    if(lineBuffer[commasCounted] == ','){
        tempArray[0] = '0';
        tempArray[1] = '0';
        tempArray[2] = '0';
        tempArray[3] = '0';
        tempArray[4] = '\0';
    }else{
        int j = 0;
        for(i = commasCounted; i < 1024; i++){
            if(lineBuffer[i] == '\"'){
                i++;
                while(lineBuffer[i] != '\"'){
                    tempArray[j] = lineBuffer[i];
                    i++;
                    j++;
                }
                break;
            }else if(lineBuffer[i] == ','){
                break;
            }else
                tempArray[j] = lineBuffer[i];
                j++;
        }
        tempArray[j] = '\0';
    }

    char* tempString = strtok(tempArray, "\n");
    return tempString;
}
```

I believe the part that's blowing up is this section:

```
        while(lineBuffer[i] != '\"'){
            tempArray[j] = lineBuffer[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
```

I just can't figure out exactly why.  Is there a way to fix this?  I don't know if this is the cause, but this is the input for lineBuffer when it breaks:

```
Color,Glenn Ficarra,310,118,43,7000,Emma Stone,33000,84244877,Comedy|Drama|Romance,Ryan Gosling,"Crazy, Stupid, Love. ",375456,57426,Steve Carell,7,bar|divorce|friend|girl|male objectification,http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1570728/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1,292,English,USA,PG-13,50000000,2011,15000,7.4,2.39,44000,
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible for i to be > strlen(linebuffer)? Make sure that that doesn't happen.

Comment: Test against '\0'` `while(lineBuffer[i] != '\"' && lineBuffer[i] != '\0'){`

Comment: Possibly the `1024` is a risk. Better pass the size as a parameter than assume 1024.

Comment: what is a 'heap buffer overflow'

Comment: You are returning a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: Do you really want the `while` to continue forever until an endquote is found? or do you want to continue until an endquote **or** the end of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems here.

First you are returning a pointer to a local variable. This invokes undefined behavior. You should allocate the string with `malloc` or duplicate `tempArray` with `strdup` and then return it.

Second you should not declare `tmpArray` of size `512`, which seems to be an arbitrary number. `tmpArray` should have at least the size to fit `lineBuffer` in it, so you should declare it as `char tmpArray[strlen(lineBuffer)+1];`

You iterate from `0` to `1023` when searching for commas, which may access `lineBuffer` out of bounds, better option would be to iterate form `0` to `strlen(lineBuffer)-1`. Since you are incrementing `i` also inside the loop you should always check if your index is inside bounds.

But all those things does not seem to be a problem for the provided test string, since it fit inside all buffers.
I think the problem is here:

```
if (lineBuffer[i] == '\"')
{
    while(lineBuffer[i] != '\"')
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

If you find a `'\"'` you want to skip everything until you find the next one. If you think about it your code does not have any effect at all, since the `while` loop can not be entered. You should change this to:

```
if (lineBuffer[i] == '\"')
{
    i++;
    while(lineBuffer[i] && lineBuffer[i] != '\"')
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, I see.  This fixed it 100%.  Thank you!  So, once the outer if loop fired, because i wasn't incremented, the inner while loop evaluated false every time, because it was still at the double quotes char that was just found.  Correct?

Comment: @Locke Exactly. You want to start the search at the next character not the current one which by definition is already `'\"'`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure index i doesn't move past the end of lineBuffer:

```
    if (lineBuffer[i] && lineBuffer[i] == '\"'){...
```